# If complex matrices $A$, $B$, $AB-BA$ are nilpotent, show that $A+B$ is nilpotent.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, lie-algebras, nilpotence

> Let $A$ and $B$ be square complex matrices, and $C=[A,B]=AB-BA$.  Suppose that $A$, $B$, and $C$ are nilpotent.  When $A$ and $C$ commute, as well as $B$ and $C$ commute, then $A+B$ is nilpotent.  The answer can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3008192/let-a-and-b-be-nilpotent-matrices-that-commute-with-a-b-if-a-b-an).

I wonder if this is true in general.  That is, is the following statement true?

> If complex square matrices $A$, $B$, $AB-BA$ are nilpotent, then $A+B$ is nilpotent.

---

This question occurs when I was studying Lie algebras.

If $~\text{ad}x, \text{ad}y~$, and $~\text{ad}[x,y]$ are nilpotent, so is $~\text{ad}(x+y)$?

I have tried some simple types, but can't find a counter-example.

Can anyone prove that this is true or just give a counter-example?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: what is ad(x+y)?

Comment: @VIVID the adjoint representation of x+y. It's an expression in Lie algebra. The question itself only requires knowledge of linear-algebra.

Comment: $$A = \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right), \quad B = \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{matrix} \right),$$

then $A^2 = B^3 = (A.B - B.A)^3 = 0$ but $(A+B)^3 = I$.

Comment: @user760870 should post as an answer.

Comment: @user760870 thanks a lot! This example can be regarded as an example of $sl_3$ in Lie algebra.